# SImplifying with LINQ - Basic selection

Tags: c#, linq, list

foreach (var person in peopleList.Where(person => person.FirstName == "Messi"))
    {
            selectPeople.Add(person);
    }

I am just wondering if there is any way to simplify this using LINQ.

Like rather than look at all the people I was trying to use LINQ to just fill a list with the "Messi"'s... was trying something like...

`var selectPeople = peopleList.Select(x=>x.FirstName=="Messi");`

Then I could just add everyone in that list without a check. But it doesn't quite work as planned.

Maybe there's no point simplifying that expression. But the question seemed worthwhile just to strengthen my LINQ knowledge.

Comment: I've now got `var selectPeople = peopleList.Where(person => person.Name == "Messi").ToList();` so I guess the question is really about how to use Select and SelectMany

Comment: `SelectMany` is used when each item can return multiple results and you want to combine them into a single result set. E.g. `IEnumerable<Child> allChildren = person.SelectMany(person => person.GetChildren());` You don't need it with your example.

Comment: Also, `Select` is often redundant when you're using extension methods with lambdas instead of query expression. But if you want to project the object into something else, use `Select`. For example, if you just want a list of LastNames when FirstName equals "Messi", you would do something like `peopleList.Where(p => p.FirstName == "Messi").Select(p => p.LastName);`, which should result in a `IEnumerable<string>` representing the last names of all the people that match the given criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close. Practically done without knowing it.

```
var selectPeople = peopleList.Where(x=>x.FirstName == "Messi");
```

That will create an `IEnumerable<X>`, where X is whatever type that's in peopleList.

The query expression syntax would be

```
var selectPeople = from person in peopleList
                   where person.FirstName == "Messi"
                   select person;
```

And to get it in concrete List format, I believe you've also already discovered the .ToList() extension.

Answer (score 1):

What type is peopleList? I believe it must be a type of IEnumerable for the LINQ to work.

```
var selectPeople = peopleList.AsEnumerable().Select(x=>x.FirstName=="Messi");
```

Since it is a `List<X>` type call `AsEnumerable()` on the list and tack on your select and it should work.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` is unnecessary. Also `Select` will result in an `IEnumerable<bool>` not an `IEnumerable<Person>`

Comment: to explain, you're selecting the result of `x.FirstName == "Messi"`, *not* the items in the list *where* the first name equals Messi. The result, as Ahmad pointed out, is a bool, which is why you'll get an `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectPeople = new List<Person>(peopleList.Where(x=>x.FirstName=="Messi"));
```

or if you already have a list:

```
selectPeople.AddRange(peopleList.Where(x=>x.FirstName=="Messi"));
```